# Is this a UART chip?

Tags: hardware, serial

Based on my understanding, a UART chip is a chip that exists on a serial card, and it is responsible for the actual sending and receiving of data over the serial port.

I want to see what a UART chip actually looks like on a serial card.

The following is a PCI serial card:

[image]

Is the chip circled in yellow the UART chip?

Comment: It's more than just a UART.  It's also includes PCI bus logic and based on the unpopulated connectors it probably also includes a second UART and a parallel interface. You can see here what a plain UART chip looks like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8250_UART

Comment: Yah, the chip looks like an MCS9835CV-BA PCI to Dual Serial and Single Parallel Controller: http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=127;74;111

Comment: Indeed; this is a multi-function chip that provides several integrated features, one of which is behaving as a UART.  If, as your question suggests, what you want is to see what a UART would look like, you would generally expect it to have a lot fewer pins than this chip has, because the job it's doing is simpler. The canonical implementation of a UART these days is the [16550](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=16550+ic).  It's a more modern version of the UART used in the original IBM PC, the [8250](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=8250+uart).

Comment: Guys **these should probably be answers**, not comments!

Comment: @Wilson The question doesn't seem to be on topic. The card looks like it's only a few years old.

Comment: This is off-topic. With a specific board it might be on-topic but I'm not sure whether that would be an interesting question.

Comment: Who said it has to be interesting? OTOH I just voted to have it reopened, but I have had second thoughts. The question isn't likely to be of use to anybody else as it stands. It needs to at least mention the board name to be reasonably searchable.

Comment: This looks superuser compatible? or maybe electrical engineering?

Answer (score 3):

That chip is an ASIX [MCS9820](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=128;74;111&PLine=74), as seen on a (current) StarTech [1 Port PCI RS232 Serial Adapter Card with 16550 UART](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Serial-Cards-Adapters/1-Port-16550-Serial-PCI-Card~PCI1S550). While it contains UART functions, the chip itself is a PCI→Serial bridge.

The chip emulates a National Semiconductor [16550](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART) UART, itself an improved version of the NS [8250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8250_UART) found in the IBM PC. 8-bit computers often had a Motorola 6850 or MOS 6551 Asynchronous Communications Interface Adapter (ACIA). These would be more in line with this SE's remit.